# Distinct no funciona en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Trato de obtener las filas pero sin duplicadas,trato de filtrar las duplicadas por la columna "fecha_pago".

```
$datos = DB::table('quincenas')->distinct('fecha_pago')->get();
```

return view('empleados\reportes\quincenas')->with('datos',$datos);

Tambien se intento asi:

```
$datos = DB::table('quincenas')->distinct()->get();
```

return view('empleados\reportes\quincenas')->with('datos',$datos);

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que si esta aplicando el distinct, solo que las fechas no son iguales (totalmente iguales.) Qué tipo de campo es fecha_pago ? Timestamp? datetime?

Comment: El tipo de dato es Varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$muestraAnio = Resolucion::orderBy('gestion', 'DESC')->distinct('gestion')->pluck('gestion');
```

Comment: De dónde sale el modelo resolución y la columna gestión, yo no los veo en la preguntav

Answer (score 1):

De la documentación<sup>1</sup> y cito:

> The distinct method allows you to force the query to return distinct results:

Que se pudiera traducir como:

> El método `distinct` te permite forcar a la consulta a devolver resultados *distintos*

Deberías usar el método `select()` para indicar que columna por la cual se deba aplicar el `distinct()`, es decir aquella que deseas filtrar por valores distintos:

Código de ejemplo:

```
Modelo::select('fecha_pago')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```

O si lo vas a hacer a través del constructor de consultas puede quedar así:

```
$data = \DB::table('tuTabla')
  ->select('fecha_pago')
  ->distinct()
  ->get();
```

Como puedes notar en ambos casos **(que ya he probado)** debes usar el método `select` para pasar como argumento a la columna deseada y posterior encadenas el método que traerá valores distintos.

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[Método distinct](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)